# How to get rid of the (Beta) from the app name on google play

Tags: flutter, google-play, google-play-console

I have deployed a flutter app on the google play as a production mode, which is this link, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=yurikanamba.lovealapp
(sorry the social login doesn't work now)
I can see the latest update from the link, like screenshots, but I can still see the word (beta) right next to the app name like this.

[image]

I sent this link to some of my friends, but they cannot see the (beta) like I do.
Do you know why I can see that and how to get rid of the (beta) right next to the app name?

I guess I should disable the Beta project in our App releases on google console, but there is nothing I can deactivate my beta release...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the same problem:

First I published my app as a public beta version then I released it to production track. However, when using my developer profile I'm still seeing this Beta title.

I have a tried to unregister from testers list, then cleared my browser cache (desktop and mobile), my Google cache but I'm still seeing it.
Try this anyway, it might work for you.

The only solution I found is to use another account that was not listed as beta tester, but it seems that for profiles who have been (or still are) beta testers, "Beta" won't go away from your app title.